# Бот на Callback API VK

Tags: php, api, вконтакте, callback

У меня есть бот на Callback API, работает он так `получает команду и выводит ответ для неё`, пример:

```
if($message == '!fractions')
 $otwet = "Узнать онлайн фракций: бла бла бла бла";
```

Но проблема в том что мне нужно использовать двойные команды.
То есть я напишу `!fraction admin` в ответ мне должно прийти `Узнать онлайн фракций:  (моя вторая команда)`
То есть мне нужно чтобы выполнилась первая команда и я получил вторую команду как параметр.

Answer (score 0):

Решил вот так.

```
if(substr($message, 0, 6) == '!stats')
            $otwet = "test";
```